# Android Webview in onCreateWindow() not loading sometimes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, webview, android-webview

I'm using onCreateWindow() in WebChromeClient and loading weburl in a webview inside dialog like in below code. This is working as expected. But sometimes URL is not loading in Webview. I'm getting blank dialog and getting error with below log messages.

```
D/bWebView: bPullDownRefresh:false isTopOverScrolled:false deltaY:4.0 downY:31.0
D/bWebView: bPullDownRefresh:false isTopOverScrolled:false deltaY:1.0 downY:68.0
D/bWebView: bPullDownRefresh:false isTopOverScrolled:false deltaY:0.0 downY:533.0
W/chromium: [WARNING:aw_contents.cc(1109)] Blocking popup window creation as an outstanding popup window is still pending.
W/cr_AwContents: Popup WebView bind failed: no pending content.
W/cr_AwContents: WebView.destroy() called while WebView is still attached to window.
```

I tried by setting different webview settings. But having same issue. Can anyone help to solve this. Following is my code.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_child_webview);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        final WebView newWebView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.wvChild);
        newWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        newWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        newWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        newWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        newWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        newWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        newWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        newWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        newWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(mContext.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());

        dialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dlg, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    switch (keyCode) {
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                            if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing() && newWebView != null) {
                                if (newWebView.canGoBack()) {
                                    newWebView.goBack();
                                } else {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                                return true;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        ImageButton ivDialogClose = dialog.findViewById(R.id.icCloseDialog);
        ivDialogClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        final ProgressBar dlgProgressBar = dialog.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        newWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                dlgProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                dlgProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        newWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
                clearPortalCache(newWebView);
                if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        ((WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj).setWebView(newWebView);
        resultMsg.sendToTarget();
        return true;
    }
```